How to fix: Option 'allowImportingTsExtensions' can only be used when either 'noEmit' or 'emitDeclarationOnly' is set
When bundling my up with rollup I get the following warning:
> [plugin typescript] @rollup/plugin-typescript TS5096: Option 'allowImportingTsExtensions' can only be used when either 'noEmit' or 'emitDeclarationOnly' is set.*

The issue is that I have noEmit set and it's still complaining.
My ts config below:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    // Type Checking
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["ES5", "ES6", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],

    // Bundler
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    // Lit.js specific
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,

    // Linting
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "rollup.config.ts"]
}


I've tried tweaking the ts config but nothing has changed.
